# Proof exponential runtime by induction

Tags: haskell, math, runtime, big-o, induction

I have a problem showing with induction that the given function

```
foo :: [Int] -> Int
foo    []  = 0
foo (x:xs) = max (max x (foo xs)) (max (-x) (foo xs))
```

which returns the max absolute value of a given list of `Int`'s , has a runtime of `O(2^n)`.

I got so far by now:

`t(0) = 1` and `t(n>1)= 2 * t(n-1) + 4` where `t` shows the sum of calls of `foo` and `max` for a list of `n` elements.

```
Base Case:            n = 0 => t(0) = 1 <= c * 2^0, for c >= 1
Induction Hypothesis: t(n) <= c * 2^n
Induction Step:       n -> n+1
                   => t(n+1) <= c * 2^{n+1}
                  <=> 2 * t(n) + 4 <= c * 2^{n+1} | Induction Hypothesis
                  <=> 2 * c * 2^n + 4 <= c * 2^{n+1}
                  <=> c * 2^{n+1} + 4 <= c * 2^{n+1}
```

which is obviously wrong and I don't know how to fix that issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to prove a tighter bound, like

```
t(n) <= c*2^n - k        (*)
```

for some constants `c` and `k`.

Assuming (*) holds by induction hypothesis, we get

```
t(n+1) 
= { recursive definition }
2*t(n) + 4
<= { induction hypothesis }
2*(c*2^n - k) + 4
<= { math }
c*2^(n+1) - 2k + 4
<= { ???? }
c*2^(n+1) - k
```

Now, we only need to choose `k` so that we can actually justify the last step, but that's easy.

Note that we also need to check the base case `t(0)`, and choose `c`.

I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove a bit more general claim. If algorithm complexity is such that:

```
 t(0) = c
 t(n) = a*t(n-1) + b
```

assuming `a>1` the algorithm's complexity is `O(a^n)`.

Let's choose `k1 = c`, `d = b/(a-1)` (this choice of `d` will become clear at the end), and `k2 = a + d`.  Let's assume that `a > c` (otherwise it would have been `k1 = min(a,c)`, `d= b/(max(a,c)-1)`, and `k2 = max(a,c) + d` but I'm too lazy to write all those `max` and `min`). We want to prove that

```
k1*a^n <= t(n) <= k2*a^n
```

but here is a twist, let's prove a bit stricter upper bound:

```
k1*a^n <= t(n) <= k2*a^n - d
```

**Base case**:

```
c <= c <= (a + d) - d
```

is obviously true

**Induction step**:

We know that

```
k1*a^n <= t(n) <= k2*a^n - d
```

is true and want to prove that

```
k1*a^(n+1) <= t(n+1) <= k2*a^(n+1) - d
```

The left side is easy:

```
t(n+1) = a*t(n) + b >= a*t(n) >= a*(k1*a^n) = k1*a^(n+1)
```

The right side is a bit more complicated

```
t(n+1) = a*t(n) + b <= a*(k2*a^n - d) + b = a*k2*a^n - a*b/(a-1) + b = k2*a^(n+1) - b/(a-1) =  k2*a^(n+1) - d
```

The last step is true because

```
a*b/(a-1) - b = b*(a/(a-1) - 1) = b*(a - (a-1))/(a-1) = b/(a-1)
```

in other words

```
a*d - b = d
```